# My auth.log is getting spammed by pam login service

Tags: ubuntu

I've been encountering an issue since some time, and I can't find a way to solve it. Thought at first my fail2ban ssh jail was not working but it appears that's not the same service.

My auth.log is getting spammed by login attempts on my pam login service. Can I disable that service ? Do I need to add a jail on fail2ban ? I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do, and I can't find many topics about that service.

Here's my log file.

Thanks

````
Sep 22 11:56:43 server login[14132]: FAILED LOGIN (5) on '/dev/pts/0' from 'dynamic-ip-adsl.metfone.com.kh' FOR 'root', Authentication failure
Sep 22 11:56:43 server login[14132]: TOO MANY LOGIN TRIES (5) on '/dev/pts/0' from 'dynamic-ip-adsl.metfone.com.kh' FOR 'root'
Sep 22 11:56:43 server login[14132]: pam_mail(login:session): pam_putenv: delete non-existent entry; MAIL
Sep 22 11:56:43 server login[14132]: pam_unix(login:session): session closed for user root
Sep 22 11:56:44 server login[14147]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/pts/6' from '222.118.99.179' FOR 'root', Authentication failure
Sep 22 11:56:44 server login[14137]: FAILED LOGIN (4) on '/dev/pts/3' from 'ip-46-231-57-70.uznam.net.pl' FOR 'root', Authentication failure
Sep 22 11:56:44 server login[14137]: pam_securetty(login:auth): access denied: tty '/dev/pts/3' is not secure !
Sep 22 11:56:44 server login[14145]: FAILED LOGIN (2) on '/dev/pts/4' from '185-198-0-165.pronet-serwis.pl' FOR 'root', Authentication failure
Sep 22 11:56:44 server login[14150]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/pts/7' from 'host-79-25-233-65.retail.telecomitalia.it' FOR 'root', Authentication failure
Sep 22 11:56:44 server login[14147]: pam_securetty(login:auth): access denied: tty '/dev/pts/6' is not secure !
Sep 22 11:56:44 server login[14145]: pam_securetty(login:auth): access denied: tty '/dev/pts/4' is not secure !
Sep 22 11:56:44 server login[14150]: pam_securetty(login:auth): access denied: tty '/dev/pts/7' is not secure !
Sep 22 11:56:46 server login[14162]: pam_securetty(login:auth): access denied: tty '/dev/pts/0' is not secure !```
````

Answer (score 0):

If a service is in the internet, you will get these kind of login attempts. This is a normal thing out there in the wild :-)

You should add fail2ban or any server you are running on the internet or use a firewall in front of the server.

Please feel free to read this very good article about [pam](https://www.linux.com/news/understanding-pam/).

**EDIT:**

For more clarification:

Stands for pseudo terminal slave.

- A pts is the slave part of a pty.
- A pty (pseudo terminal device) is a terminal device which is emulated by an other program (example: xterm, screen, or ssh are such programs).
- /dev/pts contains entries corresponding to devices. /dev/pts is a special directory that is created dynamically by the Linux kernel. The contents of the directory vary with time and reflect the state of the running system.
- The entries in /dev/pts correspond to pseudo-terminals (or pseudo-TTYs, or PTYs).
- In layman's terms the primary difference between TTY and PTS is the type of connection to the computer. TTY ports are direct connections to the computer such as a keyboard/mouse or a serial connection to the device. PTS connections are SSH connections or telnet connections. All of these connections can connect to a shell which will allow you to issue commands to the computer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why is it on the Internet and to what purpose? As I'm login in my server with SSH, I don't get how this login service is working.

Comment: PAM is a collection of modules that essentially form a barrier between a. service on your system, and the user of the service. The modules can have. widely varying purposes, from disallowing a login to users from a particular.

I assumed that your server is internet facing... because of the authentication attempts from the internet to your machine.

Comment: Yes it is a web server. But how someone can use unix login without getting connected by SSH ? Can I disable that unix login service, so they can no longer bruteforce it?

Comment: no - the pamd organizes the whole login things :-)

You should always install fail2ban in front of a webserver, especially when it is reachable via ssh or other loginservices over the internet.

Comment: Sure thing! Like I said on the first post, I have fail2ban configured for the sshd, but I'm not sure about the login thing as it is a different service than sshd, and I can't find a thing about it on fail2ban docs.

Comment: I will add some notes for PTY